# Need to monitor a Li-ion battery using a 0-10 V output

Tags: voltage, batteries, measurement

I have an ebike with a weird proprietary BMS which is broken.

I want to replace it with a standard BMS, but there's a pin coming out of a connector on the battery that sends between 1 and 10 V to the controller as a 'fuel gauge' - guessing to some ADC: 10 V being 100% charged, 0 V being empty.

It's controlled by an oddly elaborate microprocessor thing in the broken BMS. The bike doesn't work if there's less than 0.5 V on this pin.

My question is: is there some circuit I can make that does the same thing? Hooks into the battery, outputs 10 V at 42 V, 0 V at 30 V, varying linearly?

Answer (score 0):

Literally a 32 V zener diode and a resistor might do the trick.

The zener goes from +42 V over the resistor (few kΩ) to GND. The voltage above the resistor is your output.

You could also put two zeners in a row to get the correct zener voltage of 32 V. It actually needs to be 32 V at the current set by the resistor of your choice. Is 42 V the correct max. Voltage?

This circuit can be pimped depending on a first test (maybe a small value series resistor and capacitor for filtering etc.)